# Настройка always_populate_raw_post_data

Tags: php, файлы, form

Создал post форму, где со стороны клиента пользователь загружает текстовый файл и нажимает на submit. Всё!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0*

Да, из строк понятно, надо изменить свойство always_populate_raw_post_data на 0 в php.ini. Так и сделал. **Не помогло.** Похимичил с нулем - снова же, **мимо.** Что делать, народ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не хочу менять версию компилятора))