# $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA передача параметров в PHP7

Tags: php

При передачи параметров методом `POST` приходит вот такое оповещение

> Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set
>   'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the
>   php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

На просторах `stackoverflow` уже есть упоминание этой проблемы, но почему-то оставшееся без внимания: [Настройка always_populate_raw_post_data](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/602771/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-always-populate-raw-post-data)

нигде не могу найти толковое разъяснение об этом.
Знаю только, что `Deprecated` это не ошибка, а предупреждение что в следующих версиях `PHP` данный функционал может быть убран. На работе скрипта это никак не сказывается. Но всё таки... Как быть дальше?

Comment: Что-то на подобие этого `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");` не пробовали использовать? http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input

Answer (score 1):

Проблема осталась без внимания так, как есть нормальное решение в официальной документации http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php 
Которое очень легко реализовать (хоть автоматической заменой по всему проекту).

Comment: И ответ какой-то нечёткий и вопрос невнятный, надо было закрывать.